# Quote difficulties

Tags: javascript, php

I don't know how to write this code properly.
Even though it works, i can see message that the string inside variable is not defined.
I guess thats because of quotes but im not sure how to make them correct.

```
$delnick = $nick['nick'];
echo '<a href="#" class="deletebutton" onclick="delselected('.$delnick.')">usuń zaznaczone</a><br>';
```

here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delselected(delnick){
alert (delnick);
var xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "delselection.php?nick=" + delnick, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Or just use double quotes around the whole string, use single quotes around the html attributes, and plug the variable into the string. PHP parses double quoted strings for variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape quotes in PHP by using backslashes.

```
echo 'That\'s an example'
```

It works also with double quotes.

Comment: You can accept the answer if that suits you by clicking on the tick next to it.